# How to structure classes in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, object

I have been working on moving over to OOP in PHP. I have reading explanations on php.net, but I  was hoping I could get some specific answers here.

I tried to create the following example to illustrate my question. Say I have "Database",  "Products", and "Users" classes, and I want to display products if a user has access.

So I call the "Products" class "showProducts()" function, which in turn creates an instance of the "User" class, which creates an instance of the "Database" object and checks the users access level.

If the user has access, then the "showProducts()" function creates another instance of the "Database" object, and queries the database.

```
class Database{

   public function query(){ 
      //runs query here 
   }

   public function __construct() { 
      //sets up connection here 
   }

}

class User{

   public function checkAccess(){ 
      $db = new Database(); 
      $db->query( //pass in query to check access )
      //does stuff, then returns true or false
   }

}

class Products{

   public function showProducts(){

      $user = new User();

      if($user->checkAccess())
         $db = new Database(); 
         $db->query( //pass in query to get products )
      }

}
```

I was hoping someone could illustrate how to do this the proper way.

I would like to have some sort of controller class, that creates one "Database" object, that is available to all of the classes that need to access it, without having to create multiple instances of the "Database" object. I would like the same thing with the users class, so there is one $users object that all the classes can access, without having to create a new object every time I need to use something in the "User" class.

I apologize if my question is not clear, and thanks in advance for any responses!!

Thanks to everybody for the replies!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When moving form procedural to Object Oriented programming you should grasp more then just how to build classes. OOP is not writing classes, its about following best practices, principles and patterns in OOP.

You should not instantiate new objects inside another, you should give the User object, his Database object that User depends on, through constructor, or setter method. That is called Dependency Injection. The goal is to give objects to a class that needs them through constructor or setter method. And they should be instanciated from outside of that class, so its easier to configure class. And when building a class you want its easy to see what dependencies that class have. You can read about Inversion of Control principle here: [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

So then your code would look like this:

```
<?php

// User object that depends on Database object, and expects it in constructor.

class User
{
    protected $database;

    public function __construct($database)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    // -- SNIP --
}

?>
```

Now to use that user class you do this:

```
<?php

    $database = new Database($connParams);
    $user = new User($database);

?>
```

You can also use Dependency Injection using setter methods to set dependencies, but Il let you google that for yourself :)

Thats it, joust read about Inversion of Controll principle, and about Dependency Injection and Dependency Injection Containers, these are the best ways to manage classes.

I have seen lots of PHP code that is "OOP" and in fact they are only using Classes as functionality namespaces :) So joust learn about OOP principles and patterns.

Have fun! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! So if I had another class that referenced on the user class, I would pass in the $user object as a parameter as well?

Comment: Yes, you can! You can pass as many classes as you like. You can pass object through constructor if object really needs that object to work. And you can pass it through setter method if object is optional. Once you get complicated dependencies, then you can think about using Dependency Injection Container where you would describe dependencies and Container would be able to assemble object from other objects and return it to you :) You can read more on Dependency Injection and Dependency Injection Container here: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/12/do-you-need-a-dependency-injection-container

Answer (score 2):

Don't instantiate objects inside your constructors or other methods. Pass them as parameter, preferably inside a different class known as factory. This will make it easy to test your code, but also make it easy to create the objects.

Also, don't try to use singletons. This is the object oriented version of "global variables", and you do not want to use global variables. It makes testing of your code really hard, nearly impossible.

Watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI to understand why it is bad to use singletons. Especially the CreditCard example at 19:00 is worth watching.

If you really want to do it state-of-the-art, have a look at the concept of "dependency injection". Essentially, passing stuff that is needed from outside into a class is the whole secret, but there are frameworks that do this for you automatically, so you do not have to write a factory yourself anymore. These are called "Dependency Injection Container" or "DIC".

Comment: Thanks very much! Googleing factory class now. Do you know of any good general tutorials on setting up class structures for websites? Im starting to understand principles, but as far as a practical implementation, im still a little lost.

Comment: First I'd recommend that you take a look at autoloading. There are several systems to make this easy, but it boils down to organizing your classes - one class per file - in a directory tree, and aligning the class names accordingly so that the autoloader, which only gets the needed classname as a parameter can construct the path and filename the class is supposed to be in. Take a look at the Zend Framework (1 or 2) for a living example. You might get an idea of how other people name their classes there, too.

Answer (score 0):

To make one object for all your code use [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern:

```
class Database{
   private $db_descriptor;

   private function __construct(){
       /* connect and other stuff */
   }
   public static function getInstance(){
       static $instance;
       if($instance === null){
          $instance = new self();
       }
       return $instance;
   }
}
```

And you can use the same technique with users, i say more with php 5.4 you can use 1 trait for singleton pattern. 
One last tip: when you work with database and other heavy things use technique called [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization). When you improve your OOP skills look at [Doctrine Project](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) they use that techniques a lot!

Comment: Actually i would recommend looking at examples from enterprise frameworks now to get a feel for how things are done. You may not need to use the right away but they will give you a good idea of how to structure things.

Comment: Symfony2 and Zend2 Frameworks are the only frameworks worth looking at :) I know I will get lots of down votes for this. But those two are the best to learn proper OOP in PHP!

Comment: Symfony 1.x or Symfony 2 or Zend Framework would be the ones id recommend in terms of best practices. If you actually want to use a framework then those may or may not be overkill for what you need to do and you might want to look at something less complext like CakePHP or CodeIgniter.

Comment: @Limeni: Not from me. But using the full stack of either can be overkill for simple small projects. Architecture wise though, they are the only to i would ever recommend as an example of the "proper" way to do things haha.

Comment: Well i worked already with Symfony 1.* and Doctrine 1.* before - thats why i answered above. For me they doesn`t very hard. I said that didn`t work with "enterprise frameworks" because my associating, that its something like processing systems at banks.

Comment: If you have worke with sf1 and Doctrine1 then you should have a good idea of good patterns. I mean think about how `sfUser` and `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` work together to provide crednetials that can be checked for access within the controller.

Comment: In doctrine a lot of singletons, for example SomeTable::getInstance(), but the answer above says that singletons is bad practice